# Help Menu iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a design question/technical question about my iPhone app.

I have a pretty simple (read really really simple) single view application. And it does everything that I need it to do. However I find myself in need of a help view. And I really don't quite know what to do!

I have a simple helpButton() method in my main view controller, and I really just want to display a scrollview with a bunch of images that show what to do during the use of my app. However, should I make a new viewcontroller class? How do I call it from my method?

Really I was thinking of an unfortunately simple method, just putting a scrollview behind everything and hiding it. Then showing it when the IBAction is called. Horrible...

Sorry if this is elementary, I haven't needed to do anything more yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push a modalViewController. To do that just make a new viewController with the scrollview and associated data in it, then

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Create an IBAction in your new viewController and a hooked up button to that action to dismiss the modalView (something like this:

```
IBAction done {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Works, though dismissModalViewController only worked with the animated augmented to the end of it =)

Answer (score 1):

A couple options:

1) Create a new UIView object, either programmatically, or even in your existing XIB file. Use the `[self.view addSubview:view]` method to display it.
2) Create a new UIViewController with its own XIB file. Use [self presentModalViewController:anaimated:] to display it.

Either way, you'll need to add something to the new view to dismiss it when you're done.

Comment: Works perfectly (minus the i =D ) I'm super psyched!